# How to call a descriptor from inside another descriptor in maven assembly plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to create my own descriptor file in maven which will setup a zip file with a current directory structure. I would like for the jar of my project to be generated with dependencies which can be done by the built-in descriptor jar-with-dependencies.

My question is how can I tell my descriptor to call the jar-with-dependencies descriptor and include the generated jar instead of the normal jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure sequence of maven assembly plugin executions:

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>your.MainClass</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-distribution-zip</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>bin</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```